# Is there a way to do a partial text vlookup?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to vlookup partial text which will return a specific value if found within my data. I have a list of postcodes (zipcodes) and would like a vlookup to look up the first part of the postcode in order to put the corresponding country in to the column next to it. So, for example, I have the following -

Sheet 1
A1 - AB45 78H
A2 - TH6 89K
A3 - EH7 4FG
A4 - G9 6DS
A5 - G17 9IC

B1-B5 Blank - this is where I would like the country to appear.

Sheet 2
A1 - AB
A2 - TH
A3 - EH
A4 - G

B1 - Wales
B2 - England
B3 - Scotland
B4 - Scotland

Can anybody think of a formula that would help? It is also quite confusing as some of the strings are 2 letters while some are only 1 letter (like 'G')...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please give this a try. In Sheet1 B1, please type the following formula and see:

=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&WEIBULL(3,5,7,))-1)),Sheet2!$A$1:$B$4,2,0)

Hope it helps